# Lookup value based on string %in% on a df join or lookup?

Tags: r

I would like to pattern match a string in one table with a string in another to obtain a corresponding lookup value.

Example:

```
library(tidyverse)

main_df <- mtcars %>% rownames_to_column('model')

lookup_df <- data.frame(
  string = c('oyota', 'orsche', 'Ford'),
  group = c('Japanese', 'German', 'USA')
)
```

How would I search each string in lookup_df to see if it's a subset of main_df$model and if it is then get the corresponding value from lookup_df$grouping?

```
main_df <- main_df %>% 
  mutate(grouping = ???)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use a `regex_left_join` from `fuzzyjoin`

```
library(fuzzyjoin)
regex_left_join(main_df, lookup_df, by = c("model" = "string"))
```

Comment: This appears to work for my example - thanks. Something I didn't consider int he minimal example is that, since I'm actually going a match based on URLs, there are regex chars in there such as '?'. Do you know of any method that essentially joins on %in%?

Comment: @DougFir You could escape those with `\\?` or place it in square brackets `[?]`

Comment: Actually, on my actual data I've tried and failed twice now, keeps crashing my session :/

Comment: @DougFir Can you please post that exact issue as a new question.